# sources.list repository URL for Debian security updates with or without "debian-security" path?

Tags: debian, security, apt, repository, url

After installing Debian 9.1, the `sources.list` entry for security updates used this URL:

```
http://security.debian.org/debian-security
```

According to [SourcesList](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list) and [Security Information](https://www.debian.org/security/index.en.html#keeping-secure), the URL is:

```
http://security.debian.org/
```

Are these URLs equivalent for the purpose of getting security updates? Any difference? Why does the installer add the `debian-security` path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both URLs work. The server serves the same content at `http://security.debian.org/PATH` and `http://security.debian.org/debian-security/PATH`.

The URL with `/debian-security` has to exist because it's the only one that works with mirrors¹. `/debian-security` is also required if you use FTP, or if you run a release that's no longer maintained and download from `archive.debian.org`.

I don't know why the shortcut without `/debian-security` was created, but it's been mentioned in so many documents that you can count on it not to go away.

¹  <sub>Public mirrors are discouraged for debian-security, because security updates should be distributed as fast as possible. But private mirrors are useful for an organization that has many Debian machines.</sub>